# Typehead displays wrong on certain input

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, http, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using a uiTypehead for input selection.

It works well except for a simple fact. My inputs always have the form like

```
{name: "Las Vegas McCarran International (LAS)<span
class="country">United States</span>", iata: "LAS"}
```

So I insert `<span class="country">...</span>` from my backend into the string.

When I then type in "veg" into the input field, that's all fine. [image]

However, when typing in "las" instead, following happens:

[image]

What basically happens is, that my system assumes "class" to be part of my desired string  does the following in the view:

```
<span c<strong="">lass="country"&gt;United States</span>
```

Basically, it recognizes "las" as the string and puts a strong into that part so that it is not displayed correctly.

My view, service and my controller look as follows:

Service:

```
angular.module('tripdeltaApp').service('airportService',['$http',function($http){
    this.airport = function (entry) {
      return $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/airport',
        data: {'search': entry}
      }).then(function (response) {
        return response.data.map(function (item) {
          //console.log(item);
          return item;
        });


      });
    };
}]);
```

Controller:

```
 $scope.onSelect = function ($item, $model, $label,to,index) {
    $model = urlParser.cleanAirport($model);
    if(to && $scope.flightArray[index+1] && !$scope.flightArray[index+1].from) {
      $scope.flightArray[index+1].from = $model;
    }
  };
```

and view:

```
 <input type="text"
                               ng-focus="inputFocus=false"
                               ng-blur="inputFocus=true"
                               ng-model="flight.to"
                               placeholder="{{'TO'|translate}}"
                               name="arrivalAirport"
                               typeahead="data as data.name for data in getAirport($viewValue)"
                               class="form-control"
                               typeahead-editable="false"
                               typeahead-on-select="onSelect($item, $model, $label,1,$index)"
                               autocomplete="off"
                               select-on-click
                               required>
```

Any idea how to solve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your best bet is to use a Custom Template, as described in the [Typeahead example](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) with the flags, instead of putting markup into your data.

You'd change your data to be like this:

```
{name: "Las Vegas McCarran International (LAS)", country: "United States", iata: "LAS"}
```

and use a template something like this:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="customTemplate.html">
   <div>
      {{match.model.name}}
      <span class="country">{{match.model.country}}</span>
   </div>
</script>
```

**Update**
If you can't change the data on the backend, you could preprocess your data as it gets loaded into JavaScript:

```
var re = new RegExp('^([^<]+)<span class="country">([^<]+)<\/span>');

angular.module('tripdeltaApp').service('airportService',['$http',function($http){
    this.airport = function (entry) {
      return $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/airport',
        data: {'search': entry}
      }).then(function (response) {
        return response.data.map(function (item) {
          //console.log(item);
          var matches = item.name.match(re);
          item.name = matches[1];
          item.country = matches[2];
          return item;
        });
      });
    };
}]);
```

The regular expression may need some tweaking, based on the specific data you have. If any airport "name" fields have a "<", that would obviously cause trouble. You may also need to mess with spacing, location of quotes, etc.

Comment: Hey Kevin, thanks for your reply. I see what you mean. You basically say to import the typehead as templateCache and then choose this above solution. Cool!! Is there any work around since I can't do the changes in the backend at the moment